# Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017 install failed on win7sp1 64 bit.how to check?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

My customer is installing Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017 tools on their isolated environment. for the similar environment, which is windows 7 sp1 64bit, some succeed, some failed. for the failed, An install window just flash before it disappears. how to check it? is there any place we can find the installation log file? thanks.

and where can I find the requirement document for Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017? does it require the similar environment as Visual studio 2017.

Comment: Did you use web installer? Have you tried with iso?

Answer (score 0):

Try to log on to the TFS server with the setup user’s account and open the user’s temp folder. Typically this folder is `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp`. And find TFS installation log file name should resemble “dd_tfs_{}_{}.log”.

In addition, you need to check Requirements and compatibility for TFS installation at website below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=vsts